# Internet Explorer 11 Touchscreen - Prevent Pull Gesture on Page

Tags: javascript, css, html, touchscreen, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on a html5 game right now, which make use of touchevents on a canvas.
On IE11 for Windows Phone 8.1 (and maybe android / ios as well) moving the finger up or down (like scrolling) does squeeze / pull the page (as there is nothing to scroll) and leaves unfavourable whitespace.

I've tried

```
html, body, canvas {
touch-action: none;
}
```

in CSS, but with no success.

I also tried to set

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

in HTML, with no success as well.

Does someone has a fix for this behaviour? It seems quite common for most websites on IE11, but I need to let the page fixed.